# apply a custom function across certain columns in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, apply

I have the following dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

date_data1 <- data.frame(
  name = c('groupA'),
  number = as.numeric(c(1:10)),
  date1 = seq(from = ymd('2019-07-01'), to = ymd('2019-07-10'), by='days'), 
  date2 = seq(from = ymd('2019-07-02'), to = ymd('2019-07-11'), by='days'),
  date3 = seq(from = ymd('2019-06-29'), to = ymd('2019-07-08'), by='days'),
  date4 = seq(from = ymd('2019-07-03'), to = ymd('2019-07-12'), by='days'),
  date5 = seq(from = ymd('2019-07-05'), to = ymd('2019-07-14'), by='days')
) %>%
  mutate(yday = yday(date5))

date_data2 <- data.frame(
  name = c('groupB'),
  number = as.numeric(c(1:10)),
  date1 = seq(from = ymd('2019-07-01'), to = ymd('2019-07-10'), by='days'), 
  date2 = seq(from = ymd('2019-07-02'), to = ymd('2019-07-11'), by='days'),
  date3 = seq(from = ymd('2019-06-29'), to = ymd('2019-07-08'), by='days'),
  date4 = seq(from = ymd('2019-07-03'), to = ymd('2019-07-12'), by='days'),
  date5 = seq(from = ymd('2019-07-05'), to = ymd('2019-07-14'), by='days')
) %>%
  mutate(yday = yday(date5))

date_data <- bind_rows(date_data1, date_data2)
```

I want to apply the following function to date1 through date4 columns:

```
mad <- function(x, y) abs(mean(x - y, na.rm = TRUE))
```

However, I want to retain the "name" identifier.

I have asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67166214/apply-a-function-across-columns-in-r) in the past and the solution worked. However, when attempting to adapt the code, I'm running into issues.

Here's what I thought should work, based on the [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67166214/apply-a-function-across-columns-in-r).

```
apply(date_data[, 3:6], function(x) mad(date_data[,7], x))
```

In other words, I'm attempting to find the mean absolute difference (the custom function, "mad") between column 7 ("date5") and columns 3 through 5 (i.e. "date1" through "date4") for each group. The goal is to have a new dataframe that gives the mean absolute difference for each of the date columns (1-4) with two rows, one for groupA and one for groupB.

I tried mapping the function, but I get an error that "arguments imply differeng number of rows."

Here's the code for the map() that does not work:

```
date_data_test <- date_data %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  map_at(c(3:6), function(x) mad(date_data[,7], x)) %>%
  data.frame()
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: (1) `apply` has a mandatory second argument, `MARGIN=`, to which you are mis-assigning a function (or ignoring). (2) your use here is much more suited for `lapply(date_data[,3:6], function(x) ...)`, since it naturally returns a `list`, which is more compatible with a `data.frame` than the matrix (or `list`, *non-deterministic*!!) returned by `apply`.

Comment: Ultimately, if you want to replace columns `3:6` with the normalized data, then `date_data[,3:6] <- lapply(date_data[,3:6], function(x) ...)` will do that.

Comment: Thank you @r2evans. That explains why the previous code was not working. However, attempting to apply that code to my actual dataset is not working. I think the data I provided here does not provide the whole picture. I have updated the question to better reflect the true situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `across` function from dplyr:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

date_data1 <- data.frame(
  name = c('groupA'),
  number = as.numeric(c(1:10)),
  date1 = seq(from = ymd('2019-07-01'), to = ymd('2019-07-10'), by='days'), 
  date2 = seq(from = ymd('2019-07-02'), to = ymd('2019-07-11'), by='days'),
  date3 = seq(from = ymd('2019-06-29'), to = ymd('2019-07-08'), by='days'),
  date4 = seq(from = ymd('2019-07-03'), to = ymd('2019-07-12'), by='days'),
  date5 = seq(from = ymd('2019-07-05'), to = ymd('2019-07-14'), by='days')
) %>%
  mutate(yday = yday(date5))

date_data2 <- data.frame(
  name = c('groupB'),
  number = as.numeric(c(1:10)),
  date1 = seq(from = ymd('2019-07-01'), to = ymd('2019-07-10'), by='days'), 
  date2 = seq(from = ymd('2019-07-02'), to = ymd('2019-07-11'), by='days'),
  date3 = seq(from = ymd('2019-06-29'), to = ymd('2019-07-08'), by='days'),
  date4 = seq(from = ymd('2019-07-03'), to = ymd('2019-07-12'), by='days'),
  date5 = seq(from = ymd('2019-07-05'), to = ymd('2019-07-14'), by='days')
) %>%
  mutate(yday = yday(date5))

date_data <- bind_rows(date_data1, date_data2) %>% 
  as_tibble()

date_data %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(across(
    .cols = 2:5,
    .fns = ~ abs(mean(interval(.x, date5) %/% days(1))),
    .names = "diff_{.col}_date5"
  ))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   name   diff_date1_date5 diff_date2_date5 diff_date3_date5 diff_date4_date5
#>   <chr>             <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
#> 1 groupA                4                3                6                2
#> 2 groupB                4                3                6                2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>